# How to roll back a transaction correctly?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand how to work with transactions in goland and have reviewed many different tutorials in which working with closing a transaction is arranged in different ways. I have several questions that do not have a definite answer.

(1) As far as I understand, `defer tx.Rollback()` will be called after `tx.Commit()`,so `rollback` won't do anything in this case? How good is it to do this?

```
func WithTx(ctx context.Context) (err error) {
    tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    //(1)
    defer tx.Rollback()

    // work

    if err = tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

(2) How good is it to use `recover` in this case if a `panic` may occur during operation? Do I understand correctly that if there is an `error`, then `recove`r will not be executed (r == nil)`?

(3) Do I need to perform a rollback if an error occurred during the commit?

(4) How is it more correct to transfer a transaction to defer? `defer func() {tx.Rollback()}` or `defer func(ttx *sql.Tx) {ttx.Rollbac()}(tx)`

```
func WithTx(ctx context.Context) (err error) {
    tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer func() {
        //(2)
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            _ = tx.Rollback()
            err = fmt.Errorf("exception")
        } else if err != nil {
            _ = tx.Rollback()
        } else {
        //(3)
        if errCommit = tx.Commit(); err != nil {
           _ = tx.Rollback()
           err = errCommit 
          }
        }
    }() //(4)

    // work with panic
    panic("")

    
    return nil
}
```

Perhaps there are some common practices on how to properly roll back transactions?

Comment: In case of a panic, do nothing. Panics occur specifically when something went so incredibly wrong that you can't be expected to handle the failure. If something goes awry that can be recovered from, you return an error. If something blew up, then and only then should `panic` be used. The main point of `recover` is not to recover from a panic in situ, 9/10 a recovered panic leads to a graceful shutdown

Comment: (4) doesn't matter how. (3) yes, no, it depends. But basically no. This might depend on the DB used and whether your actions even allow for commit-time failure. If this is critical: Consult with your DB specialist. (2) I do not understand what "error" means here. panic-defer-recover is a tripple to handle panics, not "errors". A panic is not an "error", its a major programmer mistake that must never happen, ever. (1) IMHO: bad style.

Comment: I'm with Elias and Volker on this. Note that `defer`red functions are called _always,_ not only on panics so sticking a rollback into a deferred call with a commit on a "normal" path will at least provoke a WTF moment when another person reads the code and at most may provide unexpected results with a particular RDBMS or its particular storage engine.

Comment: While we're at it, I would strongly recommend to unlearn the term "exception" when it comes to programming in Go, and to stop thinking in terms of exceptions. [1/2] In most (all?) mainstream PLs with exceptions these exceptions are used for "normal" control flow: that is, a function either returns control to its caller or blows up with exception but since _most_ if not all errors of any severity (!) are handled in these languages using exceptions, you learn to treat exceptions merely as alternate function exits requiring funny handling. …

Comment: [2/2] Go is radically different from such languages: a panic in Go signalizes a severe problem _with the code or runtime_ — as opposed to plain errors. I mean, dereferencing a `nil` pointer is a panic in Go but failure to open a file is not — please feel the difference. Once you consider rolling back transactions in case of panics in this frame of thinking, you can see that "it depends": if your code is about to abort the whole process anyway (and you probably should), there's no point in rolling back. If you implement it in a way for it to continue chugging away, then do the rollback.

Comment: «if your code is about to abort the whole process anyway (and you probably should), there's no point in rolling back»—that's because sensible DB systems will undo an uncommitted transaction if the client's session it was made in gets terminated. Anyway, as Volker said, you need to consult your go-to DB person regarding the properties of your DB system.

Comment: Agree with everyone else here, I wouldn't worry about recovering from a panic. In my opinion, I prefer to use option 1 in your original post. It means that there's less chance of you forgetting to rollback the tx later on incase an error occurs. For MySQL's default configuration option 1 is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what needed to be said, is contained within the comments, but let's recap:

1. `panic` != `error`. Don't panic, much less if said panic is used to indicate a recoverable *error* occurred. Return the error
2. see above: using `panic` and `recover` in this case is *not* a good idea. It's bad style at best. You're abusing the `panic`-`recover` mechanism to implement something vaguely reminiscent of `try-catch`
3. Depends on the DB. If you can't commit a tx, then there's likely nothing to roll back. Check the docs of your DB. You're ignoring any error returned by your `Rollback` call anyway, and in most cases, if the commit failed, the Rollback call is basically a noop, so it's likely fine to have it, even if it isn't required.
4. Both are functionally equivalent. The latter might be someting you'll need to do if you have a bunch of defer calls with multiple transactions, but that, to me, would suggest your function itself needs refactoring/cleaning up.

So *IF* you want to roll back a transaction if an error occurred, and `panic` is not the way to do it, then how would you go about things? Well, you can handle errors when they arise, and bail out/roll back as you go:

```
func (s *Storage) FooTx(ctx context.Context, args ...any) error {
    tx, err := s.db.BeginTx(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, arg := range args {
        // perform some logic/prep work on the input
        query, err := s.processFoo(arg)
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return err
        }
        // execute query for this argument, rollback if it fails
        if err := tx.Exec(query, arg); err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return err
        }
    }
    return tx.Commit()
    // or
    if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now this is a bit verbose, but easy to wrap your head around. We can make the code a bit more succinct, at the expense of less specific error-handling, and readability:

```
// note: named return value
func (s *Storage) FooTx(ctx context.Context, args ...any) (err error) {
    tx, err := s.db.BeginTx(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // now we have a transaction, if an error happens here, we assume a rollback is required
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return
        }
        err = tx.Commit() // commit, set return error here
    }()
    var query string
    for _, arg := range args {
        // note: we're using =, not :=. We are assigning to the return variable named err
        if query, err = s.processFoo(arg); err != nil {
            return // err is set and not nil, the defer function will handle it
        }
        if err = tx.Exec(query, arg); err != nil {
            return // again, err is assigned, the defer func will roll back the TX
        }
    }
    // done, commit is handled in the defer
}
```

Should you need a rollback if the commit call fails, and you still want to use the defer stuff, then the function above should be written like this:

```
func (s *Storage) FooTx(ctx context.Context, args ...any) (err error) {
    tx, err := s.db.BeginTx(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback() // if we're returning an error, rollback the transaction
        }
    }()
    var query string
    for _, arg := range args {
        if query, err = s.processFoo(arg); err != nil {
            return
        }
        if err = tx.Exec(query, arg); err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
    return tx.Commit() // sets the return variable to whatever Commit returns
}
```

That should work (not tested the code), but personally, I'd probably opt with the first implementation. It's much, much more valuable to have clean, easy to read code, than to have code littered with `defer` calls. If you start adding `defer` calls for something as crucial as handling committing and rolling back DB transactions, then I'd be inclined to ask why, and brand it code smell 9/10 times. Nothing wrong with the occasional `defer` for things like:

```
mu.Lock()
defer mu.Unlock()
// or
ctx, cfunc := context.WithCance(context.Background())
defer cfunc()
```

To ensure you don't forget releasing a lock, or cancelling a context. I do question the decision that leads to placing logic and error handling to a defer function, away from where the error originates from, or the logic that lead to the problem. Obfuscation in the name of saving 5-10 lines of code usually means the wrong thing is being prioritised.